# How to customize carlescliment/calendar-bundle for Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, calendar

I am trying to add calendar-bundle to my Symfony2 project. I am using bundle by carlescliment

[carlescliment/calendar-bundle](https://github.com/carlescliment/calendar-bundle)

Whole installation went without any problems an it's working but I can not customize views of that bundle. I am doing everything as it is described in

[1. Override the default base template](https://github.com/carlescliment/calendar-bundle#1-override-the-default-base-template)

An unfortunately is not picking up copied files.

My CalendarBundle has been created side by side with my AppBundle and I want to use CalendarBundle inside AppBundle.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Have you ensured that your custom bundle is extending that bundle?

Comment: Yeah, I feel stupid now. Thanks sjagr! You was right!

Answer (score 0):

As sjagr metioned, it was cache

```
php app/console cache:clear
```